# Why isn't 'gets' working in my Ruby script when I run from TextMate?

Tags: ruby, textmate

When running the following ruby script:

`puts gets.inspect`

On the terminal I am prompted for input and then the `inspect` output is shown, but if I run the same script from inside TextMate using the `CMD+R` shortcut then it just outputs `nil` as if there is no `gets` method.

Why is this? From what I've read TextMate is supposed to show an input dialog when input from STDIN is requested by the script, but that isn't happening in this case.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either (`gets` in Textmate, that is). It looks like this feature has a history of disappearing from Textmate, then making an appearance in an update. It might just be really hacked together…you can probably find it in the Bundle snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this blog entry](http://blog.macromates.com/2009/interactive-input/); presumably you're on Snow Leopard?

From the comments, some users say that [this file](https://github.com/alkemist/interactive-input/downloads) has worked for them on Snow Leopard. Per @dmarkow's answer, copy this file to:
`/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/`
You may want to keep a copy of the file around as updates to TextMate may replace it.

Comment: Great link! I suspected this to be the case. Maybe when Textmate 2 comes out…we will still be alive.

Comment: Thanks! Adding that file to the path dmarkow gave fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Is there anything more recent on this? For Yosemite for example?

Answer (score 3):

Specifically, you need to copy the tm_interactive_input.dylib file linked to by Phrogz in the following path:

```
/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/tm_interactive_input.dylib
```

Keep in mind that it's possible any TextMate updates will overwrite or delete this file.

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't have had a clue where to put that file if you hadn't posted this.