# Textmate + ruby chomp problem

Tags: ruby, textmate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't 'gets' working in my Ruby script when I run from TextMate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731896/why-isnt-gets-working-in-my-ruby-script-when-i-run-from-textmate)

Am trying to run a file (p015elsifex.rb)

Using Textmate on Mac (Snow Leopard).

When I try to run the code, I get an error which reads:
NoMethodError: private method 'chomp' called for nil:NilClass
at top level in p015elsifex.rb at line 6

So it gets to line 6, and instead of  asking for keyboard input, it just quits.

Here is the code:

```
#elsif example

#Original example
puts "Hello, what's your name?"
STDOUT.flush
name = gets.chomp
puts 'Hello, ' + name + '.'

if name == 'Satish'
puts 'What a nice name!!'
else
  if name == 'Sunil'
   puts 'Another nice name!'
  end
end

# Modified example with elsif
puts "Hello, what's your name?"
STDOUT.flush
name = gets.chomp
puts 'Hello, ' + name + '.'

if name == 'Satish'
  puts 'What a nice name!!'
elsif name == 'Sunil'
   puts 'Another nice name'
end

# Further modified
puts "Hello, what's your name?"
STDOUT.flush
name = gets.chomp
puts 'Hello, ' + name + '.'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Ruby version? Runs fine for me in irb under 1.8.7 on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Run the program in a `Terminal` window instead in TextMate. As a background task it apparently doesn't have standard input.

I'm sure you can eventually get TextMate configured to do what you want but for now just keep it simple.